# How can I add/subtract data from a EJS template

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I cant figure out how to substract data from an EJS template. This is my Schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var InventorySchema = Schema({
    name: [{type: String, required: true, unique: true}],
    quantity: [Number],
    code: [String],
    price: [Number],
    stock: [{type: Boolean, default: true}]
})

var Inventory = mongoose.model("Inventory", InventorySchema);

module.exports = Inventory;
```

The below is the main query to show all my data:

```
router.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    InventoryModel.find({})
    .then((inventory)=>{
        console.log(inventory);
        res.render("inventory/index", {inventory: inventory})
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
})
```

And below is the form Where I want to add/subtract data from:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="/inventory" method="POST">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="itemName" placeholder="item name"><p/>
    <label>Quantity</label>
    <input type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="quantity"><p/>
    <button>Create</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

So here's what I'm trying to accomplish. Whatever number I enter in the quantity field, subtract that data from my mongodb database whenever I hit the create button (which is a POST)

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: Are you wanting quantity to be an Array of numbers, wouldn't it just be a number?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do an update on the existing document and use the [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator.

```
Example:
# create query conditions and update variables
const conditions = { },
    update = { $inc: { views: 1 }}; # inc accepts negative numbers

# update documents matching condition
Model.update(conditions, update)
```